Test of a view model's coroutine never finishes
data class TimerInstance(
    val isEnabled: Boolean,
    val timeElapsed: Long,
)

class TimerViewModel(val dispatcher: CoroutineDispatcher = Dispatchers.Default) : ViewModel() {
    private val _timerState = MutableStateFlow(
        TimerInstance(false, 0)
    )
    val timerState = _timerState.asStateFlow()
    private var timerJob: Job? = null

    // enable, loop as long as isEnabled, update with incr time
    fun start() {
        if (timerJob?.isActive == true) return
        timerJob = viewModelScope.launch(dispatcher) {
            _timerState.update { timerState.value.copy(isEnabled = true) }
            while (_timerState.value.isEnabled) {
                delay(1000)
                // in that second pause or stop could have been pressed
                if (_timerState.value.isEnabled) _timerState.update {
                    _timerState.value.copy(
                        timeElapsed = _timerState.value.timeElapsed + 1
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

unit test simply hangs instead of asserting an updated state
import kotlinx.coroutines.Dispatchers
import kotlinx.coroutines.ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
import kotlinx.coroutines.test.*
import org.junit.After
import org.junit.Assert.*
import org.junit.Before
import org.junit.Test

@ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
class TimerViewModelTest {
    private lateinit var viewModel: TimerViewModel
    private val testDispatcher = StandardTestDispatcher()

    @Before
    fun setup() {
        Dispatchers.setMain(testDispatcher)
        viewModel = TimerViewModel(dispatcher = testDispatcher)
    }

    @After
    fun tearDown() {
        Dispatchers.resetMain()
    }

    @Test
    fun testStart() = runTest {
        viewModel.start()
        advanceTimeBy(1000)

        assertEquals(true, viewModel.timerState.value.isEnabled)
        assertEquals(1, viewModel.timerState.value.timeElapsed)
    }
}


There are several issues that need to be addressed.
When a test is about to about to end an implicit advanceUntilIdle() is called to finish all queued tasks unil no more tasks are waiting to be executed in the test scope. In this case, however, everytime delay is called a new task is scheduled to run after the specified amount of milliseconds. Since this is done in an infinite loop you will always have a task in the pipeline, hence the test never ends.
This can be easily remedied by calling viewModel.stop() at the end. You didn't provide an implementation but for the purpose of the answer I assume it to be this:
fun stop() {
    timerJob?.cancel()
    timerJob = null
    _timerState.update { it.copy(isEnabled = false) }
}

When called it cancels the coroutine so the next time delay is executed the coroutine ends and no new task is being scheduled, therefore the test can end as well.
When you try this out you will still see the same behavior, though: The test will never stop. The reason for that is that viewModel.stop() never gets executed because the test fails before that. We'll come back to the reason why the second assertEquals fails in a bit, but first let's look at what happens when it does fail: An AssertionError is thrown and the test ends. Now, as described above, when the test is about to end all waiting tasks are executed until all are completed. This is done not only for the happy path where the test succeeded, it is also done when a test fails. Since the test failed before stop could be called you run into the same infinite loop that you started out with. Only when all tasks would be finished the failed test would be displayed, so this never happens.
While calling viewModel.stop() fixes the problem it only works when the test finishes successfully. One way to ensure it is called no matter what is to move it to a finally block:
try {
    assertEquals(true, viewModel.timerState.value.isEnabled)
    assertEquals(1, viewModel.timerState.value.timeElapsed)
} finally {
    viewModel.stop()
}

This will effectively fix the problem and the test will now always finish.
As already mentioned above you will end up with a failed test, though. The second assertEquals fails with:
Expected :1
Actual   :0

Let's have a look at what actually happens here. When viewModel.start() is called a new coroutine is scheduled, but nothing of its lambda is executed for now (*). This only happens when the virtual time of the scheduler is advanced. You do this with advanceTimeBy(1000). This will now start the coroutine and the following is executed:

_timerState.update { timerState.value.copy(isEnabled = true) }
while (_timerState.value.isEnabled)
delay(1000)
if (_timerState.value.isEnabled) _timerState.update

The execution stops after 1000 milliseconds which will be somehwere in the middle of 3. while the delay is waiting. Since 1. and 2. also take up some amount of time 3. won't be able to finish in time before the test scheduler stops the execution. That also means 4. (and its lambda) will never even start. After the coroutine is stopped after 1000ms both assertions are tested. The first will succeed but the second fails because 4. was never executed.
You can fix this by advancing a more generous amount of time, like advanceTimeBy(1500). This is enough time for 4. to finish and it is still far enough away from the second delay(1000) to finish.
(*): This behavior depends on the given CoroutineContext for launch. In your test the StandardTestDispatcher is provided and the documentation describes its behavior as "launch or async blocks will not be entered immediately".

There are some other issues with TimerViewModel that I want to point out:

As you might have realized by now the while loop will not be executed exactly every 1000ms. There are two reasons while it will take longer than that: First, you delay for 1000ms and then the flow is updated which will take some time too. Technically this could take up a lot of time because the update will have to wait for all other, concurrently running updates to the flow to finish. There probably won't any in your case, so this will most likely not be a relevant factor, but it will still take up some time to finish. It may not be noticeable at first but this additional delay will accumulate over time.
The second reason is that delay(1000) delays for at least 1000ms. There is no guarantee that it will continue exactly after 1000ms. The reason for that is that the current thread that the coroutine runs on might be occupied by some other coroutine when the time is up so in addition to the 1000ms it also needs for that coroutine to finish or at least suspend. As it is right now this probably won't be an issue but a long as you don't have a dedicated thread for your timer this is something that could happen any time.

You call _timerState.update { timerState.value.copy(isEnabled = true) } as part of the coroutine. Semantically this is not correct. The coroutine is for increasing the value every second. The timer's isEnabled should be set to true before that even begins. It won't have any noticable difference during runtime but it will make the code easier to understand.

When you update a MutableStateFlow's value everything that depends on its current value must use the parameter of the update's lambda. So, instead of
 _timerState.update { timerState.value.copy(isEnabled = true) }

you must use
 _timerState.update { it.copy(isEnabled = true) }

Otherwise it would be possible for the flow's value to have changed inbetween the call of update and the execution of the lambda. This is even more important for the second update you do:
 if (_timerState.value.isEnabled) _timerState.update {
     _timerState.value.copy(
         timeElapsed = _timerState.value.timeElapsed + 1,
     )
 }

Here you even have a condition outside of the lambda that must be moved inside it, like this:
 _timerState.update {
     if (it.isEnabled) it.copy(timeElapsed = it.timeElapsed + 1)
     else it
 } 




interesting point about the potential to wait for another coroutine running on the same thread as the delay, I thought the dispatcher would use another thread in the pool to avoid this situation.
Should I be using a coroutine, your stop implementation does not and blocks main.  As delay is not a blocking call I was unsure if start() should use a coroutine or if it similarly is OK to block main.  I used a coroutine as I thought continuously bloicking main to update a flow is not OK.

start must launch a coroutine so you can call the suspend function delay (changing start to be a suspend function would also work, but view models should never expose suspend functions, so the only way to go is to launch a new coroutine). stop, however, only cancels the job which instantly returns and is not suspending. It doesn't wait until the job is cancelled. If you would want to wait (there is no need here) you would need to call timerJob.cancelAndJoin() instead. And that would be suspending so it would need to be called from a coroutine.

As for the thread switching when the current thread is occupied, that is highly dependent on how the coroutine is configured. The Default dispatcher, for example, only has a very limited amount of threads available (by default equal to the number of CPU cores). If there even is an empty thread available is therefore dependent on the hardware that your progam runs on. In addition there might be other parts of your program that also use the same dispatcher, occupying its threads. The point is that TimerViewModel doesn't know anything about that, so no guarantees can be made in this case.
